# Prevent 'showOpenDialog' from adding a recent document entry

Tags: javascript, electron

When I open a file using [dialog.showOpenDialog](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options-callback), the opened file gets shown in the list of recent documents under Windows 10. Not much to say about the accompanying code, it's as simple as:

```
remote.dialog.showOpenDialog(...);
```

The Electron docs specifically mention how to make something show up in the recent documents list (on the [Recent Documents](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/recent-documents) page), but make no mention about this undesired automatic behavior, nor how one would go about undoing it. I also couldn't find an issue about this.

There are methods for clearing the entire list ([app.clearRecentDocuments](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appclearrecentdocuments-macos-windows)), as well as adding an item to this list ([app.addRecentDocument](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appaddrecentdocumentpath-macos-windows)), but I need to *remove* an item from this list, for which there doesn't seem to be a method.

As a sidenote, files which were *not* associated with my app also show up in the list (and again according to the docs, for a file to show up in the list of recent documents, the association has to be made).

So how can I do this, or just simply prevent a file from showing up as such?

Comment: It doesn't directly resolve your issue, but have you considered setting a custom jump list for your app, which I think may replace the default recent files list. https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetjumplistcategories-windows. This might be an acceptable solution in some situations.